# Sharing image on facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a page with 10 images (for example) and I want to be able to share them singly.
Is that possible? 
I was looking through the few examples I found, but it seems that each examples shares only 1 image at a time... Like this:

```
<meta property="og:image"content="http://site.com/path/sharedimage.png" />
```

I think that this code is for a single image, but how about if I have 10 images?

Thanks

EDIT: and how could I be able to see how many likes each image gets??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `og:image` property does not actually share this image, but rather is the image used as a "preview" when your page is shared.

If you would like to include all 10 images in this place, you could potentially randomize this property between the 10 images on the server-side.

Comment: It is a photogallery page, and photos are uploaded not at the same time, so I only want to share the last uploaded photo.